# How do I choose a local Python interpreter for pythonnet in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, python, python.net

Local Python interpreter is a new Virtualenv environment in PyCharm, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue and can confirm that this method works.

1. Ensure that you have the Python Extension installed
2. Go to Settings in VS Code
3. Type in the search bar, "python: pythonPath"
4. You may have to scroll a bit before you see the result, but it should have a blue line next to it (on the left)
5. Copy and paste the path to your python interpreter, including the file itself, in the field provided (e.g. C:/Windows/python/python.exe)

Hope this helps :)